# Generate Tags out of a Text Sentence

Tags: java, keyword, tagging, text-extraction, pos-tagger

Given a list of sentences:
ex.

1. Helicopter Tour for Two -> [Helicopter, Tour]
2. Helicopter Flying Lesson -> [Helicopter, Flying, Lesson]
3. Flying Tour -> [Flying, Tour]
4. ..
5. ...

I need to be able to produce tags (like ones shown beside each entry.)

I'm thinking of adding keywords to a database table manually.

Then,

Iterate all the list of sentences. For each sentence, tokenize the sentence, check each token against the keywords database, if found matches, generate the tags.

But this looks like it will be slow if i have a huge keywords database (a hundreds of thousands of keywords) and a huge list of sentences.

Is there a more faster and optimized solution?

Im using java and mongodb for my project.

Comment: Average length of a word in english is 5.1 letters. That means that 1 mil of words would be 5.1 mil of letters or 5.1 mil of bytes (or two bytes as Strings still not optimised), which isn't really that huge, because that's just 10.2 MB. Given overhead of a Set, which is ideal to check for presence, it's still nothing...

Comment: right, the size might be small, but the number of look ups is the concern. I just read that mongodb's indexing is o(log n) so i wonder if I will come across a performance issue when i have a million of keywords to check for each token in each sentences